# SVG image not loading in any browser

Tags: html, css, svg

I know this question has been asked a lot of times. I tried every possible solution but nothing seems to work. It is working on my friend's computers. I am uploading screenshots of icons.svg file and index.html file.
**index.html**

```
 <div class="likes__field">
        <svg class="likes__icon" width="100" height="100">
              <use href="img/icons.svg#icon-heart">
              </use>
        </svg>
 </div>
```

**icons.svg**

```
<svg aria-hidden="true" 
style="position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden;" 
version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
```

**icon-heart inside icons.svg**

```
<symbol id="icon-heart" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
<title>heart</title>
<path d="M17.19 4.155c-1.672-1.534-4.383-1.534-6.055 0l-1.135 1.042-1.136-1.042c-1.672-1.534-4.382-1.534-6.054 0-1.881 1.727-1.881 4.52 0 6.246l7.19 6.599 7.19-6.599c1.88-1.726 1.88-4.52 0-6.246z"></path>
</symbol>
```

I just checked in network tab. It blocked icons.svg due to some reason.
[image: Network tab]

Comment: Use code sample editor please

Comment: Use code snippet so we can see. 
and may be the reason behind it  is the image path.

Comment: how do you run your `html`? on the `server` or from `file:///` ?

Comment: from file. And i dont think it is a path problem too, because i have other png images in that folder too, which are running fine

Comment: Use a web server. Browsers only load one file at a time from file.

Comment: That `blocked:origin` error suggests that maybe the href `<use href="img/icons.svg#icon-heart">` doesn't match the page it's on. Does this href match the same domain and protocol of your page? Maybe trying an absolute URL would help?

Comment: Ah, didn't read the comments. If you are using `file:///`, I suspect that the blocked error is because whatever `bundle.js` is is trying to retrieve the svg with `http`, which is technically not the same origin. BTW a super easy web server can be run via: `python -m http.server 8080`.

Comment: I was able to solve it by running on server. Just wondering why it did not work from file